# How to use JavaScript with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I would like to pass data from a View to a javascript file.

I tried the way I thought would work, adding the following code to the bottom of my HTML `<head>` document and loaded static files.

```
script src="{% static 'javascript.js' %}"
```

But when I went to write `var a = {{ c }};` it did not work.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way; `static` finds the URL corresponding to that file and pastes it in there, but the file itself isn't read or processed by Django's templating engine. You need to use inline JavaScript rather than Java Script in a different file; since JS variables are global, that could be just a short blurb that registers the variable, and the rest can be done in a separate file loaded later:

```
(html here)
<script>
    var a = {{ c }}
</script>
(more html)
```

Just be aware of XSS vulnerabilities- do NOT let the `c` variable be just anything a user can input! Make it something that isn't derived from user input at all, or clean and validate the input.